# Execution AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only:

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am creating record in energy object and have to update a field with user entered value + static value while creating and updating .

```
trigger testews on Energy__c (after insert,after update) {

    if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isupdate){
      energyHandler.onAfterupdate(trigger.new,trigger.oldmap);
    }
    if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isinsert){
        energyHandler.onAfterInsert(trigger.new);
    }

}
```

**apex class**

```
public class energyHandler {
    public static boolean isExecuting = false;
    public static void onAfterupdate(List<Energy__c> lstlask,Map<id,Energy__c> energyold) {

      if(energyHandler.isExecuting ){
            // if was executed during the same context 
            // avoid recursion
            return;
      }

      energyHandler.isExecuting = true; 
      List<Energy__c> Updtaeenergy=new List<Energy__c>();
      for(Energy__c energy: lstlask) {
        if(energyold.get(energy.id).energytitle__c!=energy.energytitle__c) {
            if(energy.energytitle__c==null){
                energy.energytitle__c= 'Success';
            } else {
                energy.energytitle__c='Success'+energy.energytitle__c;
            }
        }
        Updtaeenergy.add(energy);     
      }

      if(Updtaeenergy.size()>0){
        update Updtaeenergy;  
      }

    }

    public static void onAfterInsert(List<Energy__c> lstlask) {
        List<Energy__c> newenergy=new List<Energy__c>();
        for(Energy__c energy: lstlask) {
            if(energy.energytitle__c==null){
                energy.energytitle__c= 'Success';
            } else {
                energy.energytitle__c='Success'+energy.energytitle__c;
            }
            newenergy.add(energy); 
        }
        if(newenergy.size()>0){
            update newenergy;  
        }
    }


}
```

I am getting error like execution of

> AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only:

Please help me out .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't change context records in trigger on **after** events. Read [Triggers Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)

> - After triggers are used to access field values that are set by the
>     system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to
>     affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table
>     or firing asynchronous events with a queue. **The records that fire the
>     after trigger are read-only.**

if you want to do changes in trigger context records you have to do it in **before** events

In order to have these changes to trigger context records to be saved, you don't need to perform DML in **before** event on these records.